# How to handle chrome notification pop-up using selenium webdriver using javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, notifications, webdriver, popup

If anyone has logged inside the web application using chrome browser, notification pop-up appears to allow/block notification. How to handle  notification pop-up through selenium web-driver using javascript?
I have tried various ways but I am not able to resolve this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it if you would pass `--disable-notifications` property in browser options.
For example, JS code for this action

```js
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const capabilities = {
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--disable-notifications']
    }
}
let driver = new Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).forBrowser('chrome').build();
await driver.get(yourUrl);
```

Comment: When I run the code, it says "ReferenceError: ChromeOptions is not defined" and "ReferenceError: ChromeDriver is not defined"

Comment: @RajbeerSingh not sure what version of Selenium you use, for example, I updated code snippet with one of approaches for Chrome Driver.
You just need to pass capabilities in your driver builder.